# PHP array from text

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code

```
<?php
$numbers = "'10', '20', '30'";
$the_array = array($numbers);
$match = "20";
if (in_array($match, $the_array)) echo "OK";
?>
```

But it's not working, so how can I define the **$numbers** or the **$the_array** in order for this to work? If I **echo** the **$numbers** it shows:

```
'10', '20', '30'
```

And if I put that like this:

```
$the_array = array('10', '20', '30');
```

It works, but it's not working the way it's in the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php the first code is not how you create an array, or at least now how you think it does.

Comment: you seem to know the first method of array creation is wrong, and the 2nd is right. so just use the 2nd?

Comment: I need those defined like that $numbers = "'10', '20', '30'"; and call those as $the_array = array($numbers); so that's why I'm asking how to modify the code in order to work :)

Comment: theres probably some function that converts [strings to arrays](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=php+string+to+array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for example with:

**[explode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)**

[see live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b17d3f144d01dcecfb5d5aefb31c7f423999c73f)

```
$numbers = "'10', '20', '30'";
$the_array = explode("'", $numbers);
$match = "20";

if (in_array($match, $the_array)) echo "OK";
```

or with:

**[str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-getcsv.php)**

[see live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d34e77cc4835febb247600164da955839796b4d)

```
$numbers = "'10', '20', '30'";
$the_array = str_getcsv($numbers, "'");
$match = "20";

if (in_array($match, $the_array)) echo "OK";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are initializing `$numbers`, you are not initializing it an array with three values, but rather as a string. For example, if you initialized it like this:

```
$numbers = "There are '12' inches in a foot";
```

And you echo it, you will get:

> There are '12' inches in a foot

That is because a string is echoed. This is what you did. Instead, initialize `$numbers` as an array. If you want the elements of the array to be numbers, do this:

```
$numbers = array(10, 20, 30);
```

If you want them to be strings, do this:

```
$numbers = array('10', '20', '30');
```